# How can I get php class methods in AJAX Call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am creating a mobile app with Phonegap. Because the project is server-based, I use JQuery and AJAX to connect to php files lying on a server. Now I am having the following problem:

I make a AJAX call to, say, the php file login.php by

```
$.post('http://example.com/php/login.php',
{       

}).success(
    function(data){

            console.log(data);

}).error(
    function(data){
        //return error
        console.log("Error post ajax " );           
},'json');
```

In login.php I want to use class methods, where the class is written in another php file, class.php.
So login.php looks like this

```
<?php

   require_once('http://example.com/php/class.php');

   $test = $class->test();

   echo json_encode($test);

?>
```

and class.php looks like this:

```
<?php
class CLASS {

        public function test(){
            echo "test";
        }   
}

$class = new CLASS;
?>
```

But I can not use the method test() in the class CLASS. If I write the CLASS in the login.php file, of course it works, but this is not what I want.

Has anyone some tipps for me how to tackle this problem?

Comment: What's the reason for not instantiating the class in login.php? You should keep your PHP files as modular as possible and have them do one thing and one thing only. (If its a class, it should only be a class definition, etc)

Answer (score 2):

You should be instantiating the class in login.php by convention.

This:

```
$test = $class->test();
```

Should be this:

```
$test = new CLASS();
$test->test();
```

I think you said this is not what you want, so this might fix your issue:

You are not declaring the $class variable correctly:

This:

```
$class = new CLASS;
```

Should be this:

```
$class = new CLASS();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was wondering why I should not instantiate the class just after the class?
But besides, this also doesn't work within the phonegap application...

Comment: For maintainability and readability purposes. You want to `include` your class definition and then instantiate it in the file you are using it in. Sorry, I don't know phonegap so I cannot help you any further. Does phonegap allow for inline PHP processing in its HTML/JS files?

Comment: I thought it does not, but now it works. Using the tip from soulan to use the raw server path in require_once and instantiating the class in login.php it works. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn a few basics, for example from this tutorial http://tut.php-quake.net/de/, and get some things straight. Many things you do are plain wrong

`require_once('http://example.com/php/class.php');`
you do not include like that, you include the raw path on your server, not an URL

`require_once('/path/to/your/file/class.php');`
More like this.

```
$test = $class->test();
```

this also will not work when your function looks like

```
    public function test(){
        echo "test";
    }
```

this, your function has to return the value

```
    public function test(){
        return "test";
    }
```

to achieve what you try.... consider getting some basics straight first would be my first advice, keep in mind I just want to help you because you will struggle more often if you don't get those basics and know the language you are using ;)

Comment: Great tips! Reading into the PSR coding standards could give him some good pointers as well! http://www.php-fig.org/psr/

Comment: I write it a little bit too fast. Of course there must be a return in the funtion. I understand what you mean with require_once, I also used it in my website. But the problem in phonegap is, that all files hast to be html,css or js files. So, how can I get access to the class.php where I have a couple of functions in the class?

Comment: You simply need a server to process the php files, phonegap can not do this, or you have in case of iOS to write this part you want to be dynamically in objective-c, or in case of android in java and connect it to the stuff you do with phonegap